# How should I print HI in huge block letters enclosed in a box of *?

Tags: c++, c++11, pretty-print, ascii-art

I am required to output Hi in huge block letter which is enclosed in a box of * in C++. [image of the output required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWWRj.jpg) So far I've only managed to figure out a basic way where I print each line by line, but is there any smarter way to do it?

Heres what I managed so far

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  cout << "**********************" << endl;
  cout << "*                    *" << endl;
  cout << "*   HH    HH     II  *" << endl;
  cout << "*   HH    HH     II  *" << endl;
  cout << "*   HH    HH     II  *" << endl;
  cout << "*   HH    HH     II  *" << endl;
  cout << "*   HHHHHHHH     II  *" << endl;
  cout << "*   HH    HH     II  *" << endl;
  cout << "*   HH    HH     II  *" << endl;
  cout << "*   HH    HH     II  *" << endl;
  cout << "*   HH    HH     II  *" << endl;
  cout << "*                    *" << endl;
  cout << "**********************" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, this is the best you can do.

Comment: It would be more general if you read a file with the characters and output it, and smarter if you had only the basic letter shape and could scale it and draw the box depending on the string and scale -- since you cannot go to school anyway ;-)

Comment: Calling something "smarter" seems rather subjective. Is is smarter to over-engineer a solution when you don't need options/flexibility? Without more concrete criteria, I think this question falls under the "generates opinionated answers" category. (Sorry.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your program a bit easier to modify by using the symmetry of what you are printing:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void n_lines(int n)
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < n; i++)
      cout << "*   HH    HH     II  *" << endl;
}

void star_line()
{
    cout << "**********************" << endl;
}

void empty_line()
{
    cout << "*                    *" << endl;
}

int main(){
  star_line();
  empty_line();
  n_lines(4);
  cout << "*   HHHHHHHH     II  *" << endl;
  n_lines(4);
  empty_line();
  star_line();
  return 0;
}
```

This will produce the same output, but it's much easier to change the size and such.

Comment: Oh my god, this is actually so much smarter, thanks for the advice ! much appreciated ! :D

Answer (score 6):

You can do it that way:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  for (int i = 0; i < 13; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 22; ++j) {
      char c = ' ';
      if (i == 0 || i == 12) c = '*';
      else if (j == 0 || j == 21) c = '*';
      else if (i >= 2 && i <= 10) {
        if (j >= 5 && j <= 12) {
          if (i == 6 || j == 5 || j == 6 || j == 11 || j == 12) c = 'H';
        }
        if (j == 17 || j == 18) c = 'I';
      }
      cout << c;
    }
    cout << "\n";
  }
}
```

I don't recommend it though.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if there was some approach like this, but considering all the different numbers involved and another way of doing it by just using the symmetry to my full advantage, I'd avoid this too haha. Thanks for the help though ! :D

Answer (score 5):

Most of the other answers are not, in my opinion, "smarter" than yours.

They're *shorter* than yours. The program may be smaller than yours. But they're still idiosyncratic and not useful for anything other than printing "HI". So why not just do it in a straightforward manner like you have?

Now, if you wanted to be able to print *arbitrary* box-enclosed messages in this form - then you'd have a reason to try to "optimize", use loops etc. For that, you could perhaps look at the source code of the [figlet](http://www.figlet.org/) utility, which takes arbitrary text and uses custom font files:

```
$ figlet -f bigascii12 HI

 ##    ##   ######  
 ##    ##   ######  
 ##    ##     ##    
 ##    ##     ##    
 ##    ##     ##    
 ########     ##    
 ########     ##    
 ##    ##     ##    
 ##    ##     ##    
 ##    ##     ##    
 ##    ##   ######  
 ##    ##   ######
```

Answer (score 4):

In this case, we're drawing a picture: I would say the best option is to just draw the picture directly. You could use loops and the like to cut down the length, but in my opinion that just hides the structure of what you're trying to draw for no real benefit.
If you were trying to generalise a method of printing large text that would be a different story, but that's not the case here.

In that case, probably the best you can do is use a raw string literal. For example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << 
R"(**********************
*                    *
*   HH    HH     II  *
*   HH    HH     II  *
*   HH    HH     II  *
*   HH    HH     II  *
*   HHHHHHHH     II  *
*   HH    HH     II  *
*   HH    HH     II  *
*   HH    HH     II  *
*   HH    HH     II  *
*                    *
**********************)" << "\n";
}
```

Another alternative is to store the image in a file, and just print out the contents of the file.

Comment: NIce idea to use a raw string literal.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in one line of code if you use the newline character, but it would be ugly and wouldn't make sense to do it that way:

```
cout << "**********************\n*                    *\n*   HH    HH     II  *\n*   HH    HH     II  *\n*   HH    HH     II  *\n*   HH    HH     II  *\n*   HHHHHHHH     II  *\n*   HH    HH     II  *\n*   HH    HH     II  *\n*   HH    HH     II  *\n*   HH    HH     II  *\n*                    *\n**********************" endl;
```

The way you have it right now is just fine. You could also use a switch, or an if statement to ask print the right line for the what value the counter is, but really there is no reason to change what you already have.